# In userform when i am encountering a space i just want to give a error message with deleting just the space?

Tags: excel, vba

Code for just deleting the space in userform input box in vba not tge entire data

Answer (score 2):

You can use Replace to remove a space. If the text is held in a variable s then

```
 s=Replace(s," ","")
```

Will remove all spaces from the contents of s

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [KeyDown event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keydown-keyup-events) for your TextBox and disallow spaces:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeySpace Then KeyCode = 0
End Sub
```

With this code the user cannot enter any spaces at all. The disadvantage of this is the user can still copy/past spaces into the TextBox.

With a [Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/change-event) you can prevent this too:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1.Value = Replace$(TextBox1.Value, " ", "")
End Sub
```

This will replace also pasted spaces.